# Почему при создании текста/div через функцию, на экран выводиться только текст на белом фоне?

Tags: javascript, html

При этом, всё что было до этого, удаляется.

Вот скрипт функции:

```
function clicking() 
{                                                                               
     document.write("Hello world");
                            
}
```

Скрипт активируется при нажатии на другой div:

```
onclick=\"return clicking();\"
```

В итоге, такая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее извиняюсь за глупость, Java Script начал изучать недавно.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: А какой результат работы этого скрипта вы ожидаете? Вообще, так и должно это работать, ничего необычного.

Comment: При нажатии на div, выпадали другие div. Но куда там div, когда текст не выводится обычный...

Comment: после того как загрузка завершилась вызов `.write` - приводит к выводу заново - полному стиранию предыдущего

Comment: Восстановить можно нажатием на браузерную кнопку назад.